# How to get the index of an array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, math

I'm trying to print the array index using pointers arithmetic. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?
in particular "j" I would like you to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int b[10] = {2, 8, 4, 7, 1, -45, 120, 78, 90, -6};
    int *pb, j = 0;

    for(pb = &b[0]; pb < &b[10];) {
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", j, *pb++);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well you could also do  `j++` in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
int main(void) {

    int b[10] = { 2, 8, 4, 7, 1, -45, 120, 78, 90, -6 };
    int *pb, j = 0;

    for (pb = &b[0]; pb < &b[10]; pb++) {
        printf("[%td] = %d\n", pb-b, *pb);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In pointer arithmetic you can get the index difference with subtraction: `pb-b` is the index of the element that `b` points to in array `pb`. I also moved the `*pb++` to the `for` loop increment in order to avoid an off-by-one-error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
int b[10] = {2, 8, 4, 7, 1, -45, 120, 78, 90, -6};
for (int* pb = b; pb != b + sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b); pb++)
    printf("[%d] = %d\n", pb - b, *pb);
```

Comment: I tried to execute the code but I get this error: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", pb - b, *pb);
                 ~~           ^~~~~~
                 %ld
I have a change %d with ld... why does it need a long decimal?

Comment: @RobertoRocco: Because on your platform, it is possible that the size of a pointer is 64 bits, in which case, `pb - b` yields a 64-bit value, which should be printed via `%ld`. Since we know that `pb - b` is at most 10, you can cast it to `int` and keep the `%d%`, o in other words: `printf("[%d] = %d\n", (int)(pb - b), *pb);`.

Comment: In fact, even if the size of pointer on your platform is 32 bits, the compiler might be configured to a very restrictive level, where a pointer should be treated as `long int`. In any case, you can check pointer size of your platform via `sizeof(void*)`.